# Pyspark merge dataframe rows one array is contained in another

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I don't even know what the best title to phrase the questions.

I have the following dataset

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([\
            (["1", "2","3","4"], ),\
            (["1","2","3"], ),\
            (["2","1","3"], ),\
            (["2","3","4","1"], ),\
            (["6","7"], )\
], ['cycle', ])
df.show()

+------------+
|       cycle|
+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|   [1, 2, 3]|
|   [2, 1, 3]|
|[2, 3, 4, 1]|
|      [6, 7]|
+------------+
```

What I would like to have at the end is:

1. remove the permutations
2. keep only the row with the maximum row that contains the all other sets

I can use `sort_array()` and `distinct()` to get rid of the permutations

```
df.select(f.sort_array("cycle").alias("cycle")).distinct().show() 
+------------+
|       cycle|
+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|      [6, 7]|
|   [1, 2, 3]|
+------------+
```

What I would like to reduce the dataset with Pyspark is:

```
+------------+
|       cycle|
+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|      [6, 7]|
+------------+
```

So check somehow that `[1, 2, 3]` is part of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and only keep 
So the Python Subset command `A.issubset(B)` applied in the Pyspark, Spark way over a column

The only way I can currently think of is a horrible iterative loop over very row which will kill every performance

Comment: Just as a hint in a direction: Did you have a look at rolling window functions?

Comment: what is your spark version, 2.4+ or below?

Comment: My Spark version is 2.4+

Comment: I tried around with window functions to aggregate but did not find a way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you might try is to first find all `cycle`s with at least one *superset* (exclude self) by using a *self join* to find `d2.cycle` which satisfies the following conditions:

- `size(`[array_except](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except)`(d2.cycle, d1.cycle))==0`: none items in *d2.cycle* are excluded in *d1.cycle* (EMPTY array will satisfy)
- `size(d2.cycle) < size(d1.cycle)`: the *size* of *d2.cycle* is less than the *size* of *d1.cycle*:

and then take a left_anti join to exclude the above list from the original dataframe, finally run sort_array and drop_duplicates(or distinct):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_sub = df.alias('d1').join(
      df.alias('d2')
    , expr('size(array_except(d2.cycle, d1.cycle))==0 AND size(d2.cycle) < size(d1.cycle)')
).select('d2.cycle').distinct()

df_sub.show()
#+---------+
#|    cycle|
#+---------+
#|[1, 2, 3]|
#|[2, 1, 3]|
#+---------+

df.join(df_sub , on=['cycle'], how='left_anti') \
  .withColumn('cycle', expr('sort_array(cycle)')) \
  .distinct() \
  .show()
#+------------+                                                                  
#|       cycle|
#+------------+
#|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
#|      [6, 7]|
#+------------+
```